# ionic cordova with googe pay

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to integrate Google Pay into my web application using the documentation provided by the Google Pay API. I followed https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial?hl=en

When using the installed APK of my web application, I encounter the error "Something went wrong. To make this purchase using Google Pay open this website in a browser".
And when using the `--livereload` mode, I get the error

> Google Pay APIs should be called in secure context!.